# Getting an std::array reference without using templates

Tags: c++

If a function receives an array range (begin/end) as pointers, is there a way to treat that as `std::array` again?

```
void xyz(int* begin, int* end) {
  // at this point i know that at this memory range there's
  // an array<int> of end - begin size
  // is there any way i can get that back?
}

int main() {
  array<int, 5> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  xyz(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

I know that i can pass `x` as parameter but i'd have to specify it's size. The way around that is to use templates, but i wonder is there a some way to reconstruct a typed reference to `x` without using templates and without copying it?

If (begin/end) isn't enough to reconstruct the type inside `xyz` is there any other way to give `xyz` memory representation of an array, and let it reconstruct the type... trusting that it's there at this memory address?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213902/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-spanish-getting-an-stdarray-reference-without).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` is implemented as a `struct` holding a C-style fixed-length array as its sole data member.  The `begin()` iterator is *usually* a raw pointer to the 1st element of the array <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: @bitmask makes a good point in comments: "Note that `std::array<T,N>::iterator` does not have to be a raw-pointer. It usually is, but doesn't HAVE to be. Nor does it have to be convertible to a `T*`. So your code is invalid C++ and compiles because of an implementation detail of your compiler.*"</sup>

The address of the 1st element of an array is guaranteed to be the same address as the array itself. And the address of the 1st member of a struct is guaranteed to be the same address as the struct itself.  So, *in theory*, provided that the `begin` iterator is really a raw pointer to the 1st array element, then you *should* be able to type-cast `begin` to a `std::array*` pointer - but only if you know *at compile-time* the *EXACT* template parameter values that were used to instantiate that `std::array`, eg:

```cpp
void xyz(int* begin, int* end) {
  using array_type = array<int, 5>; // OK
  array_type *arr = reinterpret_cast<array_type*>(begin);
  ...
}

int main() {
  array<int, 5> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  xyz(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

However, this will fail miserably if you can't guarantee that `begin` comes only from a `std::array`, and is a raw pointer to its 1st element.

And while you *can* determine the necessary `T` template parameter from the type of the iterators begin passed in, you *cannot* determine the necessary `N` template parameter using just iterators.  That value must be a compile-time constant, but getting the distance between the 2 iterators can only be determined at runtime instead:

```cpp
void xyz(int* begin, int* end) {
  using array_type = array<int, ???>; // <-- can't use (end-begin) here!!!
  array_type *arr = reinterpret_cast<array_type*>(begin);
  ...
}
```

Or:

```cpp
template<typename Iter>
void xyz(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  using array_type = array<iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, ???>; // <-- can't use (end-begin) here!!!
  array_type *arr = reinterpret_cast<array_type*>(begin);
  ...
}
```

The whole point of using iterators as function parameters in the first place is to abstract away the container type so it is not known or needed.  So, it is very difficult, if not impossible, to determine the original container type from information gleamed from its iterators.

So, in this situation, if you really need access to the `std::array` then you are best off simply passing the whole `std::array` itself, not its iterators:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
void xyz(array<T, N> &arr) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  array<int, 5> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  xyz(x);
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the in depth explanation, very helpful. but question is about another way other than templates

Comment: This looks UB. Like ... extremely!

Comment: @bitmask yes, very

Comment: @bitmask can you, please, elaborate?

Comment: @RickySpanish There are a lot of IFs that have to be TRUE for this to even be possible to work.  I've tried to explain them in my answer for you.

Comment: @RickySpanish Elaborate on what?

Comment: @bitmask sorry i didn't see your explanation that begin doesn't have to be a pointer

Comment: @RickySpanish The whole answer boils down to: **No**, there is no legal way to convert an iterator to a container into the container itself.

Comment: @NathanOliver safest illegal way to treat a block of memory as specific type essentially using it's functionality. The problem extends out of arrays i think. it's like i have this chunk of memory that i know for fact it's of type X, and i want to treat it like so

Comment: @RickySpanish There is no safe illegal.  UB means you can't reason about the code anymore and that means it's not safe.

Comment: @RickySpanish "*i have this chunk of memory that i know for fact it's of type X, and i want to treat it like so*" - That is what [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) exists for: "*[reinterpret_cast] is purely a compile-time directive which instructs the compiler to treat `expression` as if it had the type `new_type`.*". But there are a lot of restrictions on how `reinterpret_cast` can be used safely and *legally*. This situation falls under "type punning" and really violates the [strict alias rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau but i can't reinterpret cast an `array` this is what's bugging my little brain. But again it's because of the size needing to be compile time known, so i thought what if there's a way to dynamic cast at runtime... the type is there and the size is known

Comment: @RickySpanish you can `reinterpret_cast` a *pointer* of one type into a *pointer* of another type, which is exactly what I show in my answer.  `dynamic_cast` won't work, because `std::array` is not a polymorphic type (no virtual methods), plus you still have to specify the *exact* type to cast to, which goes back to the issue of not knowing the array's `N` parameter. Same with `static_cast`, too. Without knowing the *exact* `std::array` template parameters, there is simply no *casting* that you can perform. That doesn't mean you can't access the array's *data*, you can (via the iterators).

Comment: alright, so there's no way on earth that i can use `end-begin` to specify the size at runtime

Comment: @RickySpanish *at runtime*, you can certainly calculate the size, eg: `size_t size = end - begin;` or `auto size = std::distance(begin, end);`  You just can't use that value IN TEMPLATE PARAMETERS, eg: `size_t size = ...; std::array<int, size> *arr = ...;`, as template parameter MUST be known *at compile-time* only.